# wcf routing - how to edit config file programatically at runtime

Tags: wcf, wcf-routing

I'm trying to build a core with the routing service technology (in wcf .net) that discover its clients automatically with `DiscoveryService` and then write them into the config file with specific filters so that the core will be able to route messages between the clients.

I succeeded to discover the clients with `DiscoveryService`, but i'm trying to open new config file with the `RoutingConfiguration` object, and add the new endpoints I discovered through the `RoutingConfiguration.filterTable` property but it doesn't work. I also tried to look for examples in other sites but i didn't find anything similar.

I don't know if i'm making a mistake, or if I didn't understand well how to open new configuration file and edit it at runtime programatically.

Comment: What is your code so far?

Comment: Note that in some cases (most notably IIS), modifying the config file while the application is running will restart your application (and quite possibly get you into an infinite loop).